# Making a webpage accessible only via a specific domain or form submit

Tags: php, session, redirect, paypal, registration

I am reasonably new to web development and I am just trying to expand my knowledge for a couple of sites I'm working on to become more effective.

My question is; if I have a `register.php` page in my directory and I only want to make it accessible via the re-direct back from an external PayPal checkout can this be done?

I am obviously aware that I would usually use `$_SESSION` to protect the content of a page, however I am wondering how I can use this before a user has registered. I am aware that I could use a PayPal API however I wondered whether there is a way of only displaying the register form from the re-direct without a `$_SESSION` in place as the user will not yet be registered. I would need to protect the `register.php` page as I would want to ensure a payment has been made first. I will probably look down the route of API at a later date, I just wanted to know if there is a way of displaying secure content to unregistered users.

Comment: After the paypal checkout, won't you have some sort of record stored in DB? Would that be something you can check against before showing the page?

Comment: You can check out the `$_SERVER` variables, specifically `$_SERVER[HTTP_REFERER]` but it's not 100% I don't think

Comment: @user2191572 The referer is worse than useless.

Comment: do they visit any page on your site before going to papal? if so you can start a session.

Comment: Hi Moe, Yes I will look to log something in the MYSQL database for reference, however with this payment information being stored for instance in a PayPal account there would be much need. I was just wondering how I could store this info in the DB if the checkout was an external page? Any thoughts on how I could do this? Thank you.

Comment: I would strongly recommend they register first at your site before going to PayPal, then you avoid problems connecting payments to visitors and the last step is a simple activation switch on the account.

Comment: Hi Dagon, yes they would visit the site first and press a PayPal button which would take them to the external payment page. What are your thoughts?

Comment: start a session when they visit the page with the button, or even after they press it

Comment: Hi Jeroen, If I was to do it this way, how could I confirm the payment before they are officially registered, it doesn't matter which way round it happens, I am just struggling to find a solution of how I could confirm the payment after the re-direct from the external PayPal page? Any thoughts? Thank you

Comment: Again, I'm not sure that after the redirect that the session would be the same, as its from an external page? I may be wrong?

Comment: Would my solution be to have a cart actually on the website rather than going to an external page?... I'm just wondering if there is a way of doing it from the re-direct though.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really familiar with PayPal api but i wonder if you could provide PayPal url with unique url based on some calculation eg hashing date etc... every time PayPal is used? This way you have daily changing url to prevent unauthorized access.

```
$url = 'ENTER-URL-HERE?hash=' . md5(date('Y-m-d) . 'saltstring');
```

And in your page, just check if hash is set and is what it should be:

```
if(isset($_GET['hash']) && $_GET['hash'] == $url)
  //Do stuff
```

Another way to check if ipaddress is allowed would be

```
if(AUTHORIZED-IP == $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR])
  //Do Stuff
```

Comment: Hi AngularAddict, thanks for your post. I will have a look into this, sounds like a potential way round it. Thank you.